# Save groovydocs to a file for HTML documentation

Tags: groovy, documentation-generation

How can I

1. Save the groovydocs to a separate file
2. And fetch the file content to be used for HTML page documentation

or a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a handy Ant task for [groovydocs](http://groovy.jmiguel.eu/groovy.codehaus.org/The+groovydoc+Ant+task.html) - it produces standard HTML javadoc documentation, so may you need not to postprocess it.